# How to find the target position of an arrowhelper in three.js?

Tags: three.js

I wish to add two arrows in the scene where the second arrowhelper's origin is the tip of the first arrowhelper. Cuurently I have direction, origin vector and length of first arrowhelper. How can I position the second arrowHelper on the tip of the first arrowHelper?

Comment: you need to post complete minimal testable code example

Comment: Also, you may try accepting answers. I see you have other questions that have answers but none have been accepted.